# Using Associativity to Reduce Number of OR Gates

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra

EDIT: I think I'm probably more confused than I realise. My question could also be phrased as "how was the given diagram constructed from the expression, particularly with reference to the OR gates?"

Say I have the logic expression `X = A AND ((B AND C) OR (B AND D) OR (C AND D))`

It looks like I need 3 `OR` gates to handle the possible conditions for the second input to the `AND` gate.

However, if I add brackets to the expression, like so:

`X = A AND (((B AND C) OR (B AND D)) OR (C AND D))`

it looks like I can reduce the number of `OR` gates to just 2.

Is this correct? Is this a standard method of simplifying expressions using the associative property of Boolean algebra?

[image]

Comment: I see in both expressions only 2 OR gates

Comment: yeah, it's unclear how you came to three OR gates. Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

The first expression has one, 3-input OR gate. The second has two, 2-input OR gates. These two expressions are logically equivalent.

Whether either one is **simpler** than the other depends on your definition of **simple**. Does simple mean fewer **gates** or does simple mean that you only use 2-input gates? In the real world, optimization is usually done to minimize silicon area and propagation delays.